# ajax call php script no errors not records

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Guys please have a look what's wrong in my code which is basically called by ajax post. same records are displaying in other page but which i click `load more button` the get_data.php does not seems to fetch records from db and iinstead  iam getting a blank page.

i have tried echo $cat, $row they display records in index.php when clicked on load more.

```
<?php
require('includes/config.php'); 
$cat = 2;
$row = 2;

$rowperpage = 2;

echo $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * from blog_posts WHERE catID = :catID ORDER BY postID ASC LIMIT :row, :rowperpage");
$sth->bindParam(':catID', $cat, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':row', $row, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':rowperpage', $rowperpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();

$results = $sth->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$html = '';

 $html .= '<div class="row">';
 $html .= '<div class=" col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">';
 $html .= '<div class="row">';
 $html .= ' <div class="leftbar_content">';

 foreach ($results as $rows) {
   $id = $rows['postID'];
     $img = $rows['postImg'];
            if(!empty($img)){
            $img ="<img src='".DIR."uploads/images/".$img."' alt=''";
            }else{
            $img = "";
            }
            $youtube = $rows['postYoutube'];
            if(!empty($youtube)){
            $youtube ='<div class="videoholder"> <iframe width="720" height="450" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$youtube.'?autohide=1&fs=1&autoplay=0&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&controls=1&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>';
            }else{
            $youtube = "";
}                   
                $html .= '<div id="post_'.$id.'">';

            $html .= '<div class="single_stuff wow fadeInDown">';
              $html .= '<div class="single_stuff_img"> <a href="'.DIR.'post/'.$rows['postSlug'].'">'.$img.$youtube.'</a> </div>';
               $html .= '<div class="single_stuff_article">';
                $html .= '<div class="single_sarticle_inner">  <a class="stuff_category" href="'.DIR.'category/'.getCatUrl($rows['catID']).'">'.getCatName($rows['catID']).'</a>';
                  $html .= '<div class="stuff_article_inner"> <span class="stuff_date">'.date('jS M Y', strtotime($rows['postDate'])).'</span>';
                    $html .= '<h2><a href="'.DIR.'post/'.$rows['postSlug'].'">'.$rows['postTitle'].'</a></h2>';
                  $html .= '<p>'.$rows['postDesc'].'</p>';
                 $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '</div>';
              $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';

            $html .= '</div>';

}

echo $html;
```

here is my js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Load more data
    $('.load-more').click(function(){
        var row = Number($('#row').val());
        var catid = Number($('#catid').val());
        var allcount = Number($('#all').val());
        row = row + 2;
        if(row <= allcount){
           $("#row").val(row);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'get_data.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {row:row,catid:catid},
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $(".load-more").text("Loading...");
                },
                success: function(response){
                    // Setting little delay while displaying new content
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // appending posts after last post with class="post"
                        $(".post:last").after(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
                        var rowno = row + 4;
                        // checking row value is greater than allcount or not
                        if(rowno > allcount){

                            // Change the text and background
                             $(".load-more").text("Sorry , No more posts to load");
                            $('.load-more').css("background","#FB0925");
                        }else{
                            $(".load-more").text("Load more");
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('.load-more').text("Loading...");
            // Setting little delay while removing contents
            setTimeout(function() {
                // When row is greater than allcount then remove all class='post' element after 3 element
                $('.post:nth-child(3)').nextAll('.post').remove().fadeIn("slow");
                // Reset the value of row
                $("#row").val(0);
                // Change the text and background
                $('.load-more').text("Load more");
                $('.load-more').css("background","#333333");
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

shared the codes, hope i get some solutions.

thanks

Comment: please post your javascript function .

Comment: @TrươngCôngHậu i just updated it with js

Comment: 1- $results = $sth->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); print this result    2-alter response in ajax function may be you got the issue.

Comment: i did this echo print_r($results); and get  Array ( ) 1

Comment: with this query data shows $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE catID = 2 ORDER BY postID ASC LIMIT 1,2')->fetchAll();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

Normally when working with the LIMIT clause When in emulation mode (which is on by default), PDO substitutes placeholders with actual data, instead of sending it separately.

Try to turn emulation off.

by :   `$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );`

Then change this :

```
echo $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * from blog_posts WHERE catID = :catID ORDER BY postID ASC LIMIT :row, :rowperpage");
```

To

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * from blog_posts WHERE catID = :catID ORDER BY postID ASC LIMIT :row, :rowperpage");
```

Comment: getting this error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

Comment: using it like this i get records showing $results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE catID = '.$cat.' ORDER BY postID DESC LIMIT '.$row.','.$records_per_page.'')->fetchAll();

Comment: but i need the parameters in BindParam but it just does not work if i bind them

Comment: try to execute(array(YOUR PARAMS))

Comment: $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * from blog_posts WHERE catID = ? ORDER BY postID ASC LIMIT ?,?");
$sth->execute(array($cat,$row,$rowperpage));
$sth->execute();

$rows = $sth->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: did that no records gets fetched